# The rightmost derivation is possible with the same rule of leftmost derivation

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, parsers, derivation

Can someone please help me in understanding the statement. What does it exactly mean?

What I think it means is that:
the derivation produces by the leftmost derivation is also possible with rightmost derivation.

What do you think guys?

Comment: I think we are missing some context. Also, why is it so important for you to understand this particular statement? Some statements just aren't worth it. Perhaps the author made a mistake, or retained a spurious statement, or put it out of context.

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what I'm thinking. We are given this question in the class task but I'm not getting what it exactly means.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask your TA or lecturer, then.

Comment: Yes, I'll do that